# How to create a .app from a Mono application in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, bundle

I have downloaded the zip version of [KeePass](http://keepass.info). To run it I have to open the Terminal, go to wherever I unzipped it and run `mono KeePass.exe`. Is there someway I can take all the files in that zip file and that command and bundle them up so I get a KeePass.app I can stick in my Applications folder that can more easily be run?

Comment: There is a Mac version of keepass you know. http://keepass.info/download.html

Comment: @Chris: Hm... do you mean under *Contributed/Unofficial KeePass Ports and Builds*? Can only see one there and looks like it's based on version 1. Can version 1 work with files from version 2?

Comment: You are correct.  I use 1.x files so they work everywhere. I think for 2.x files you need a 2.x version. (i.e. windows)

Comment: @Chris: The 2.x version should work under Mono though. But it seems to crash on my Mac... Think I might be missing some UI libraries or something...

Comment: If you get it working please post details.  I would love to upgrade ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I found this, which seems to promise what you're looking for.

[Running KeePass 2.x on OSX using macpack](https://www.md3v.com/running-keepass-2-x-on-osx-using-macpack)

It uses macpack to create a .app file.  See the comments - some of them indicate how to update the icon.

> Fortunately, I found KeePass. It can run using Mono under OSX, but it
>   can be a hassle to run. The default way of doing that is:
>
> - Open Terminal and navigate to KeePass directory
> - Typing: mono KeePass.exe
>
> We can do this:
>
> - Install Mono Framework
> - Download latest version of KeePass 2.x and unpack it
> - Open Terminal and navigate to unpacked KeePass folder
> - Run the following command:
>
>   ```
>   macpack -o:. -m:winforms -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ libCocoaSharpGlue.dylib -r:KeePass.chm -r:KeePass.XmlSerializers.dll -r:KeePassLibC32.dll -r:KeePassLibC64.dll -r:License.txt -r:ShinstUtil.exe -r:./XSL -n:KeePass -a:KeePass.exe
>   ```
> - This will create a KeePass.app file that you can drag into your \Applications folder, and you should be all set.

You can also use [MonoMacPackager](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/monomacpackager/)

Comment: Because KeePass has somewhat frequent updates, I decided to go with this for OSx: https://macpass.github.io/ and I have to say, I'm impressed with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a bundled AppleScript application that includes all the necessary binaries in its Resources folder, or you might be able to use Platypus: http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus